# How big is Gingerbread 2.3.5 on internal 8GB memory?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

How much space does the Gingerbread version 2.3.5 occupy on the internal memory drive ?
I've bought the Samsung Galaxy Player 5.0 and it promised  8GB, when I checked the size it said 5GB and only 4.85GB are actually available. What's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty normal. The 8GB iPod Touch is similar - iOS takes a significant portion of its storage.

The device itself has 8GB of storage, but any OS takes space - particularly Samsung's flavor of Android, which has a lot of stuff added (Which, unfortunately, they don't want you to be able to remove).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and taking the time, dotVezz !! I appreciate it. I think I can live with the fact that you explained, just for being able to use my Samasung Galaxy which is a fantastic little device, helping me avoid cell phone bills, and so many other things.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Christian If you're happy with the answer, please feel free to upvote it and mark it as accepted =)

Comment: Do note too, that your standard device formatting stuff also applies (i.e. how you don't really get 1tb of hard drive space from a 1tb hard drive) Formatting eats up a chunk of it as well.  Fortunately the Galaxy Player has a microSD card slot, if i correctly recall, so that can be used to extend the capacity of the device, should you need more space -- microSD cards are also relatively cheap too, provided you're not looking for a ton of space.